# Get the group with the highest count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write an SQL query which will give me the groups with the highest value.

I have a table `Crime` which has two foreigns keys leading to tables `District` and `CrimeType`. I have to select 'the most popular' crimes and their districts.

So far I managed to write something like this:

```
SELECT CrimeType.Category, District.Name, count(*) as NoOfCrimes
FROM Crime
INNER JOIN CrimeType ON Crime.id_crime = CrimeType.id
INNER JOIN District ON Crime.id_district = District.id
GROUP BY CrimeType.Category, District.Name
ORDER BY NoOfCrimes
;
```

And this almost works, but I see the every crime and number of occurences in each of district, like:

```
Rape   | Downtown | 10
Murder | Downtown | 5
Rape   | Queens   | 2
Theft  | Queens   | 7
```

Expected output:

```
Rape   | Downtown | 10
Theft  | Queens   | 7
```

I need only the most common crime from each district - withouth repeating.

EDIT: Added expected output. Now I see each type of crime with its district and number of occurences, but I need the most common crimes from each district.

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Comment: use `limit 1` after `order by NoOfCrimes desc` to get the top row

Comment: @TheOpti, do you need to include the count? Add your expected outcome

Comment: @dbajtr I edited my post

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find appropriate query. Here it is:

```
SELECT Category, Name, NoOfCrimes
FROM (
    SELECT CrimeType.Category, District.Name, count(*) as NoOfCrimes
    FROM Crime
    INNER JOIN CrimeType ON Crime.id_crime_type = CrimeType.id
    INNER JOIN District ON Crime.id_district = District.id
    GROUP BY CrimeType.Category, District.Name
) AS MostCommonCrimes
WHERE NoOfCrimes = (
    SELECT MAX(NoOfCrimes) from MostCommonCrimes a where a.Name = MostCommonCrimes.Name
);
```

Unfortunately, @dbajtr and @iSR5 answers do not give correct results.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use ROW_NUMBER() function to get the top one, this should work:

```
WITH Crime(Category,
           Name,
           NoOfCrimes,
           num)
     AS (
     SELECT CrimeType.Category,
            District.Name,
            COUNT(*) AS NoOfCrimes,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY COUNT(Crime.id_crime))
     FROM Crime
          INNER JOIN CrimeType ON Crime.id_crime = CrimeType.id
          INNER JOIN District ON Crime.id_district = District.id
     GROUP BY CrimeType.Category,
              District.Name
     ORDER BY NoOfCrimes)
     SELECT Category,
            Name,
            NoOfCrimes
     FROM Crime
     WHERE num = 1;
```

I haven't been able to test it though

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have your own query, I would prefer to use current query (in your post) and just converted into a subquery which would help you to filter your results even more.

Example :

```
SELECT CrimeType, District, MAX(NoOfCrimes) AS TotalCrimes 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
    CrimeType.Category  AS CrimeType, 
    District.Name       AS District, 
    count(*)            AS NoOfCrimes
    FROM Crime
    INNER JOIN CrimeType ON Crime.id_crime = CrimeType.id
    INNER JOIN District ON Crime.id_district = District.id
    GROUP BY CrimeType.Category, District.Name
) Crime
GROUP BY CrimeType, District
ORDER BY TotalCrimes DESC
```

I've not taste it, but I'm sure it'll be useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the query using ROW_NUMBER() as:

```
select Category,
       Name,
       NoOfCrimes
from(   
SELECT row_number() over(partition by District.Name order by count(*) desc) as rownum,
CrimeType.Category, District.Name, count(*) as NoOfCrimes
FROM Crime
INNER JOIN CrimeType ON Crime.id_crime = CrimeType.id
INNER JOIN District ON Crime.id_district = District.id
GROUP BY CrimeType.Category, District.Name
--ORDER BY NoOfCrimes
)as T
where rownum =1
;
```

[SQL Fiddle here..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec496/1) hope this helps!!